# Crash and Collision - Kinematics Question?

Tags: collision-detection, kinematics

Vancouver is 300 km away from Seattle. Two friends, one leaving from each city on a bike want to find a campsite between the two cities. One cyclist starts from vancouver at 25 km/h. His friend will start 2.0h later from seattle at 32 km/h. How far from Vancouver do the friends meet?

Attempt:

dA + dB = 300

vA(t) + vB(t+2) = 300

25t + 32t + 2 = 300

t = 4.14 s

now how do i find the distance travelled by each cyclist?

not sure if this is even the correct direction, but any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

btw- correct answer is 160 km

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stay consistent with your labelling, write the position of the Vancouver cyclist as $ \ x_A  = 25 \ (t+2) \ $ and the position of the Seattle cyclist as $ \ x_B = 300 - 32t \ . $  We are calling the location of Vancouver $ \ x = 0 \ $ by doing so. Remember that the Vancouver cyclist is the one who has been pedalling two hours *longer*.

You want to solve for the time when $ \ x_A = x_B \ . $  That time $ \ T \ $ can then be entered into either position function to find the distance from Vancouver where they meet.

Note: the answer *rounds off* to 160 km., in case you are wondering about the "ugly" fractions.

Comment: why dont we use xA + xB = total distance? , where xB is simply 32t?

Comment: but what was the thinking behind the 300 - 32t position for the seattle cyclist? I still dont understand how it was derived :/

Comment: In this approach, $ \ x \ $ represents the distance of either cyclist from Vancouver, which is the reference point for the question.  We want here to find when their positions are _the same_.  The time $ \ t \ $ here represents how long the Seattle cyclist has been pedalling, so the Vancouver cyclist was at $ \ x = 0 \ $ at time $ \ t = -2 \ , $ 2 hours before "Seattle" got underway.  "Seattle" starts at $ \ x = 300 \ $ and is getting _closer_ to Vancouver, so their speed must be entered as negative.

Comment: If you use distances, the one change that would need to be made is that $ \ d_B = 32(t-2) \ $ , since you are counting from when "Vancouver" started cycling, so "Seattle" has been underway two hours _less_.  That is equivalent to the method **user92774** describes.  (And don't forget to distribute the "32" over the "2", as well as the "t".)

Comment: oh that makes sense, but why cant we represent the position of seattle cyclist by 32t, where the equation is 25(t+2) + 32t = 300?

Comment: but if you did 32(t-2) for seattle, then the vancouver position would only be 25t

Comment: You _can_ use $ \ 25(t+2) + 32t = 300 \ , $ but then $ \ t \ $ represents the time that the Seattle cyclist has been pedalling; you get $ \ T = \frac{250}{57} \ $ hours.  The time that "Vancouver" has been pedalling is then 2 hours _more_ than this. The equation you intended [should be $ \ t - 2 \ $] in your post uses the time that the Vancouver cyclist has been pedalling, which is then $ \ T = \frac{364}{57} \ , $ which you'll see is the same result, with the Seattle cyclist having ridden two hours _less_.  It's all a matter of which cyclist you wish to refer to.

Comment: OMG wow that makes SOO much sense, thank you so much for taking your time in order to give me an extremely thorough answer you have no idea how long i spent on this simple question (pathetic i know!!), and I very much i appreciate it!!!!!!

Comment: It is important to have the time references sorted out properly -- you will likely meet up with more problems of this sort in the future...

Comment: Can't wait!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:  Suppose that the friends begin cycling at the same time, but instead of starting from $300$ kilometers away from each other, they start $250$ kilometers away from each other. If $x$ is the answer to this equation, the answer to your original equation will be $x + 50$.

Comment: This is a fine way to get the answer also, provided one is careful to keep straight which endpoint the problem wants the distance measured from.  I would show this approach to students next, once they get used to writing position functions correctly and understand how to find "closing speeds".

Comment: Indeed, your solution is probably more valuable as it is more applicable to the general case.

Comment: @user92774 nonetheless thank you!

Comment: @user92774  I don't feel so particularly -- there are a number of equivalent techniques that work; one just has to be careful about what reference points or times are being used and what each symbol represents.

Answer (score 2):

Your direction is fine.  It is good to define your variables, like $dA$ is the distance traveled by the one from Vancouver, etc.  The vB should be multiplied by $(t-2)$ as the one from Seattle leaves two hours later, so that cyclist is traveling two hours less.  You dropped multiplying the $2$ by vB, so it should become $64$ (with a minus sign).  The unit on $t$ should be hr, not s.  One cyclist traveled $vA(t)$ and the other $vB(t-2)$